# Non-nullable instance field 'image must be intialized' and imagefile must be intialized

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am getting error that i should initialized both image and fileimage

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
{
  String result="";
   File image;
   Future<File> imageFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to avoid the warning, depending on what is your use case:

1. Marking the fields as "late", personally I prefer to avoid it since it could throw exceptions at runtime if the field is being accessed before initialization, so use this with caution.
2. Marking the fields as nullable by adding '?' to the field type, and then assign them a value when you load the widget/object, however this will require you to check for null case ,using either the '?.' syntax or checking nullability the old fashion way if (x != null). I find it to be more readable than the late modifier.
3. Initializing the fields with a default value if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use late like this

late  File image;
late   Future imageFile

Or

File ? image;
Future?  imageFile